# I now receive advertisements from a site used by a guest on my wifi she was on OS X I'm running LInux did they track my IP address only?

Tags: ip, user-tracking

I seems a little strange that the only thing in common between me and my guest is that she was on my wifi and thus using my wan ip address, yet I am receiving advertising from a site she used.  I'm not surprised that she sees those ads, but it seems odd that a completely different system, os, useragent, no cookies being shared, different users and email addresses, etc. would be receiving the same ads.  So also then, if I would use a VPN, would I then be receiving ads from activity of other users who used one of the VPN's IP addresses also?

Comment: Of course you would. Note that tracking the IP address, an item that is *needed* by the server to communicate with your client, is the most obvious thing to track (albeit somewhat useless or at least weak, as your case shows). -- IIRC, something like this is how some daddy learned that his daughter had been looking for information about pregnancy tests ...

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you *"receive advertisements"*, I assume you mean you see them on your Browser vice receiving them on email or some other application?

Comment: Yes, on my FF browser, she was using Chrome.  I agree it is a weak way to track considering entire offices have many users on the LAN side with one WAN IP, and the fact that I had no interest in Elvis jewelry.